# insert image into html on demand via javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html5-document that contains this element:

```
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

The document loads, the user logs in, and some new text gets loaded and successfully displayed via Ajax (using jQuery). After a while (when the user makes a click) a new image should be inserted into the `imgContainer`-div.

I do this with this jQuery-command:

```
$("#imgContainer").html('<img src="newImage.png" alt="">');
```

The file `newImage.png` is located in the same directory as the html-file and the javaScript-file. But it does not appear in the browser-window. But it is correctly inserted into the source-code. I checked this with the developer-tools of my browser (safari). This tools don't report any error. But still the image is invisible. When I look into the list of resources I can see no `newImage.png`. Obviously the browser didn't load it. But why?

The image appears in the browser-window when I enter its URL. So the browser is able to load it. But it does not when I modify the html-document. Why?

Must I add some additional code to ma javaScript to tell the browser to load the image? If so: Can you tell me this code?

**Edit:**

try here: http://jsfiddle.net/YCs66/1/

Comment: You're code looks correct.  Do you see the image file in the network tab of the developer tools (i.e. is the browser actually requesting the image)?

Comment: are you absolutely sure that your new `<img>` element is being injected into the page correctly? it is possible that your script executes before the container element loads, resulting the jQuery attempting to inject the image into an element that doesnt exist, is your code placed in a block that runs after DOM loads? here have a look, your code works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/LWpjr/

Comment: @Banana has a good point, remember, has good practices your scripts should be included at the end or your HTML document, this ensures that HTML will be rendered before you start interacting with DOM. Also remember to take advantage of document ready function when using jQuery. Document ready is executed until all HTML has been loaded.

Comment: The container is part of the original html-document. The script is executed some seconds later. I can see the resulting html-code in safari's web-inspector. the former `<div id="imgContainer"></div>` has changed into `<div id="imgContainer"><img src="newImage.png" alt=""></div>` When I select the code-line in the inspector, then a tool-tip appears in the browser window with the text `img 0px x 0px`.

Comment: what is `<img scr=` ?? `scr` means nothing, it should be `src` man. (referring to your jsfiddle)

Comment: [Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCs66/2/)

Comment: You should also be closing your `<a>` tag - `'<img src="newImage.png" alt=""/>'` (note the slash)

Comment: OMG! It was a simple typo! *grrrr* And I even made the same typo in fiddler! How stupid is this? - Need a break.

Comment: @enhzflep - you don't need a closing slash for self-contained elements. it's not 2006 anymore.

Comment: @enhzflep: the 4th word in my posting is "html5" which means: Elements that have no content (like "img") don't need a slash. If you want you can write it, but a html5-document is also wellformed if you omit it.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - and the second word of my comment is `should` which means it's advisable, but not required. It's faster to parse if the the slash is included. Not by much, granted - but it is still the better practise. I knew browsers could handle situations when it wasn't present, but didn't know that an html5 document is well-formed even with their ommision, so thanks for that. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/ZCL2U/1/

Replace this

```
$("#imgContainer").html('<img scr="https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png" alt="">');
```

with this

```
 $("#imgContainer").html('<img src="https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png" alt="">');
```

As I checked in your Fiddle, you have given source attribute as "scr".

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `.html()` method only puts in the HTML without actually parsing the attributes for the `DOM element`. Here is the solution

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" action="">
<input type="button" value="click me"
onclick="loadPic()">
</form>
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var loadPic = function () {
    alert("loadPic started");
    $("#imgContainer").html('<img/>');
    $("img").attr("src", "https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png");
    alert("loadPic finished");
};
```

[PLAYGROUND](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/KbHtp)

---

**Note** that the `<img/>` that is performing `.attr("src", ...)` is an `asynchronous` function. As a result, 2 `alert()`s will come out before the actual image is being loaded.